# Changing specific text with javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I have a html file, and I want to change some text of it.

I want to create a form to change this text, like this:

```
<div id="texto">
    Texto original da div.
</div>

<form name="formTexto">
    <input type="text" name="novoTexto" id="novoTexto"/><br/>
    <input type="button" value="Alterar texto" onclick="alterarTexto()" />&nbsp;
    <input type="button" value="Adicionar texto" onclick="adicionarTexto()" />
</form>

<script language="javascript">
    function alterarTexto() {
        var novoTexto = document.formTexto.novoTexto.value;
        document.getElementById("texto").innerHTML = novoTexto;
    }

    function adicionarTexto() {
        var novoTexto = document.formTexto.novoTexto.value;
        document.getElementById("texto").innerHTML += "&nbsp;"+novoTexto;
    }

</script>
```

But, I want the "form" in another file, because I'm creating an Admin Area to learning more about javascript and PHP.

Can anyone help me?

Ps.: Sorry, please! My english is poor!

Comment: Its not clear how this relates to an admin area...but obviously you should not rely on javascript for security (if that's what you're thinking about doing, which is not clear).

Comment: Okay, understood . Do you know any example, using mysql ? I wanted to start from scratch, but I'm short time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a file to get started.

Here's the index.php that displays the content:

```
<div id="texto"><?php echo file_get_contents('content.txt'); ?></div>
<a href="admin.php">Edit</a>
```

And here is the admin.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_POST['password'] == 'changeThis!') {
  $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
}
if($_SESSION['loggedin']) { // are we logged in?
if($_POST['content']) {
  file_put_contents('content.txt', $_POST['content']);
  die('Saved: ' . $_POST['content']);
}
?>
<form method="post">
  <textarea name="content"><?php echo file_get_contents('content.txt'); ?></textarea>
  <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
<?php
} else {
?>
  <form method="post">
    <input type="password" name="password">
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
  </form>
<?php
}
?>
```

It goes without saying that this is a quick way of getting you *started*, but please familiarize yourself with how Sessions work, how to do Templating (with Twig or Smarty) and how to work with a database.

Comment: Thanks! It works for me!

Comment: @HebertRichard then please be so kind and accept this answer.